# Remote command execution failed: stat: cannot stat Nagios User

Tags: linux, bash, tomcat, nagios

I have a script which checks for the log patterns in Nagios. When i run the same via nagios user, it gives me an Error

"Remote command execution failed: stat: cannot stat `/home/tomcat/services/abcd-1.23.123/logs/abcd-abcd.log': Permission denied"

Here is the debug info of the script. Any solutions ?

**::/usr/local/nagios/check_hierfetcherlog.sh:44+stat -c %s /home/tomcat/services/abcd-1.23.123/logs/abcd-abcd.log
stat: cannot stat `/home/tomcat/services/abcd-1.23.123/logs/abcd-abcd.log': Permission denied**

Here are the permission for the above path

```
/home                               - drwx------ 18 tomcat tomcat 4096 Oct 27 16:25 tomcat 
/home/tomcat                        - drwxr-xr-x 61 tomcat tomcat 4096 Oct 27 14:55 services 
/home/tomcat/services/              - drwxrwxr-x 10 tomcat tomcat 4096 abcd-1.23.123 
/home/tomcat/services/abcd-1.23.123 - lrwxrwxrwx 1 tomcat tomcat 64 Oct 16 23:46 logs -> 
                                    -rwxr-xr-x 1 tomcat tomcat 42493867 Oct 27 04:12 abcd-abcd.log
```

Comment: And what are the permissions on that file and the directories leading up to it?

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 tomcat tomcat /home/tomcat/services/abcd-1.23.123/logs/abcd-abcd.log

Comment: And the directories above that file from `/home/tomcat` and down? Are they at least 001 (o+x)?

Comment: /home   - drwx------ 18 tomcat   tomcat   4096 Oct 27 16:25 tomcat     /home/tomcat - drwxr-xr-x 61 tomcat tomcat    4096 Oct 27 14:55 services                                                                       /home/tomcat/services/  - drwxrwxr-x 10 tomcat tomcat  4096 abcd-1.23.123                                                /home/tomcat/services/abcd-1.23.123 - lrwxrwxrwx 1 tomcat tomcat    64 Oct 16 23:46 logs ->                                              -rwxr-xr-x 1 tomcat tomcat 42493867 Oct 27 04:12     abcd-abcd.log

Comment: i do have nagios user in tomcat group                                        tomcat:x:91:nagios

Comment: Update the post with that information instead of shoving into a comment so you can format it properly but at the very least that first permission will block the nagios user.

Comment: Updated Post with permissions, Please revert back if needed anything more.

Comment: As I said, that first line indicates that only the `tomcat` user can do anything with that directory. Thus the nagios user is unable to get any farther than that.

Comment: As 'tomcat' user, run: chmod g+rx /home